# Website (asp.net) to send emails via remote mail server, and not end up in spam folders

Tags: asp.net, localhost, spam, smtpclient

So, the setup is this, 2 separate servers...

Web server, has IIS7, MS SMTP

Mail server has MailEnable

On the web server, I'm sending an email from an ASP.Net app, via the mail server, and it is getting marked as spam

If I send an email through the mail server, just from a normal mail client, it doesn't get marked as spam.

I'm sure this is a setup issue, but what am I likely to have done wrong?

web.config:

```
<smtp from="website@domain.co.uk">
  <network host="mail.mymailserver.co.uk" userName="website@domain.co.uk" password="password" />
</smtp>
```

asp.net, just a normal SmtpClient send:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

*a random gut feeling reckons it's probably sending through the local SMTP server, then on to MailEnable, and that's giving it weird headers...just a thought though*

The headers contain this line: Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: best guess record for domain of transitioning website@mydomain.co.uk does not designate unknown as permitted sender)

I've no idea what it means though (the  part looks suspicious)

Comment: This is not a programming question, so Stack Overflow isn't the right place for it. If you really want help with this, you should post the actual hostname you are using for the SMTP server and the actual domain in question (I'm betting the SFP record is not setup correctly) - if you do I'll happily take a look.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought this was likely to be the best place for it as it's the kind of thing programmers come up against rather than server adminy people - maybe wrong. The SPF record is setup to just accept everything at the moment to rule that out as an issue.  Do you think it could have something to do with going through a localhost SMTP server that isn't setup properly, but eventually getting to Mailenable, but then it looks like the original sender went through the web server's SMTP?

Comment: I think this is a legit SO question since it's something software developers encounter.

Comment: @IP Yeah I think that having it forward through an inappropriately configured mail server could cause that problem. You could try creating something like a Google Mail account and using it's SMTP service to test (or, alternatively try sending via whatever the SMTP server for the servers provider is) - you would need to add the host to the SPF record of course. If you don't want to post the domain & hostname then I'd at least post the SPF record for the domain (because you will see this error if the SPF record is not formatted correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Received-SPF** error is related to [Sender Policy Framework](http://www.openspf.org/). What you need to do is change the DNS records on your domain to include your web server (usually its IP address) as a valid sender.

The [SPF website](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) has details on how to setup this configuration.

**Edit:** It's up to the mail client how to interpret: `Received-SPF: softfail`. So when you allow any domain to send emails, you might still run into this error. From http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Received_Header:

> When an SPF query returns any other result, the MTA should add an advisory header to the message of the form "Received-SPF: neutral" or "Received-SPF: pass". That way, a spam filter further down the road can take that header into account as part of a more balanced decision.

Comment: The domain has an SPF record though - just a really generic one that says anything is allowed to send for it (don't normally do that, but to try and diagnose this issue I tried to rule it out).

Comment: I've just noticed that the word unknown was hidden from my question, I have put this back in